# integrating wowbook with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have successfully integrated wowbook (https://github.com/yapro/wowbook) with ionic but every time I flip the book,
ionic send me back to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`.

It's like ionic doesn't recognize the state `#/book`.

Here is my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BKpXGfU64t69ITWiMtQh?p=preview

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('').previousTitleText('');

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "login.html"
    })

    .state('book', {
        url: '/book',
        templateUrl: "book.html",
        controller: function($stateParams, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#features').wowBook({
                        height: 500,
                        width: 800,
                        centeredWhenClosed: true,
                        hardcovers: true,
                        turnPageDuration: 1000,
                        numberedPages: [1, -2],
                        controls: {
                            zoomIn: '#zoomin',
                            zoomOut: '#zoomout',
                            next: '#next',
                            back: '#back',
                            first: '#first',
                            last: '#last',
                            slideShow: '#slideshow',
                            flipSound: '#flipsound',
                            thumbnails: '#thumbs',
                            fullscreen: '#fullscreen'
                        },
                        scaleToFit: "#container",
                        thumbnailsPosition: 'bottom',
                        onFullscreenError: function() {
                            var msg = "Fullscreen failed.";
                            if (self != top) msg = "The frame is blocking full screen mode. Click on 'remove frame' button above and try to go full screen again."
                            alert(msg);
                        }
                    }).css({ 'display': 'none', 'margin': 'auto' }).fadeIn(1000);

                    $("#cover").click(function() {
                        $.wowBook("#features").advance();
                    });

                    var book = $.wowBook("#features");

                    function rebuildThumbnails() {
                        book.destroyThumbnails()
                        book.showThumbnails()
                        $("#thumbs_holder").css("marginTop", -$("#thumbs_holder").height() / 2)
                    }
                    $("#thumbs_position button").on("click", function() {
                        var position = $(this).text().toLowerCase()
                        if ($(this).data("customized")) {
                            position = "top"
                            book.opts.thumbnailsParent = "#thumbs_holder";
                        } else {
                            book.opts.thumbnailsParent = "body";
                        }
                        book.opts.thumbnailsPosition = position
                        rebuildThumbnails();
                    })
                    $("#thumb_automatic").click(function() {
                        book.opts.thumbnailsSprite = null
                        book.opts.thumbnailWidth = null
                        rebuildThumbnails();
                    })
                    $("#thumb_sprite").click(function() {
                        book.opts.thumbnailsSprite = "images/thumbs.jpg"
                        book.opts.thumbnailWidth = 136
                        rebuildThumbnails();
                    })
                    $("#thumbs_size button").click(function() {
                        var factor = 0.02 * ($(this).index() ? -1 : 1);
                        book.opts.thumbnailScale = book.opts.thumbnailScale + factor;
                        rebuildThumbnails();
                    })

                });
            }, 0);

        }

    });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem with my Repo in ionic what basically is wrong as far as i think is  flipping your page appends the url so that's why it can't see the state in the state list and hence its going to the otherwise state thats your login state .

Just go through the code and see where you see the url is being appended and try to resolve that

If i get some time next weekend i will surely help

Still there are other flipping tutorials online you can use anyone among those

Regards 
Ezaz

Comment: Yes, flipping the page appends the url at the increment of 1,3,5,7, 
#/book, #/book/3 and so on.
is it possible for $stateparams.id to increment by 1,3,5

Comment: let me have a look once i get some time till then you can change the css to make it fit fr every device 
nothing is impossible my friend

Answer (score 0):

I just found this on wowbook wiki, wowbook has it own hash url just like ionic. so both hash url is conflicting.

to solve the problem simply turn off wowbook hash url(#/book) by adding to your controller updateBrowserURL: false